# registration via php

Tags: php, mysql, registration

I've been reading alot of tutorials on how to and looking at samples regarding registration. I have my database config file, reg_form and register-exec files. When I try on a production server, I get file not found for register-exec.

Here's my reg_form:

```
<?php

session_start ();


?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && count       ($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 ){
echo '<ul class="err">';
foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) {
    echo '<li>',$msg,'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
 }
?>
</body>
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="register-exec.php">
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th>Full Name</th>
<td><input name="fname" type="text" class="textfield" id="fname" /></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Email Address (Must be valid)</th>
<td><input name="email" type="text" class="email" id="email" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Password (must not be longer than 6)</th>
<td><input name="password" type="password" class="textfield" id="password" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Confirm Password</th>
<td><input name="copassword" type="password" class="textfield" id="copassword" />"</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="form_submitted" value="1" />"<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />"</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

The following is the register-exec.php file, I'm not sure where I went wrong with it.

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Include database
require_once('db_conn.php');

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false; 

//Create a random 6 digit cid for users
$new_cid = mt_rand(100000, 999999);

//Create random activation key
$act_key = mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand().mt_rand();

//Connect to mysql
$link = mysql_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$link){
die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
  }

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
die("Unable to select database");
}

//Sanitize the values
$fname = clean($_POST['fname']);
$email = clean($_POST['email']);
$password = clean($_POST['password']);
$copassword = clean($_POST['copassword']);

//Make sure they submitted the form
if($_POST['form_submitted'] == '1'){    


//Make sure they inputted information
if($fname == '') {
$errmsg_arr[] = 'Full Name missing';
$errflag = true;
 }
if($email == ''){
$errmsg_arr[] = 'Email missing';
$errflag = true;
 }
if($password == ''){
$errmsg_arr[] = 'Missing password';
$errflag = true;
}
if($copassword == ''){
$errmsg_arr[] = 'Confirm password missing';
$errflag = true;
}
if( strcmp($password, $copassword) != 0 ){
$errmsg_arr[] = 'Passwords do not match';
$errflag = true; 
} 
$sql="INSERT INTO users (fname, email, password, act_key, cid) VALUES ('$fname',  '$password', '$act_key', '$new_cid')";
if (!mysql_query($sql))
{
die('Error:' . mysql_error());

} 

 echo "An email has been sent to $_POST[email] with an activation key. Please check your mail to complete registration.";

//Send the first activation email
$to          = $_POST['email'];
$subject = "VMATSIM Registration";
$message = "Welcome to VMATSIM. You or someone using your email address has completed registration at vmatsim.net. You can complete reigstration by clicking the following link:\rhttp://vmatsim.net/register-exec.php?$act_key\r\rIf this is an error, ignore this email and you will be removed from our system.\r\rRegards, VMATSIM Team";
$headers = 'From: noreply@vmatsim.net' . "\r\n" .

'Reply-To: noreply@vmatsim.net' . "\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject,$message,$headers);


//User is activating
} else {

$queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($queryString == $row["act_key"]){
        echo "Congratulations" . $row["fname"] . " is now the proud owner of a VMATSIM account.";
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET act_key = ''";


        if(!mysql_query($sql))
        {
            die('Error:' . mysql_error());
        }
    }
}

}
?>
```

Any pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: Why do you $new_cid = mt_rand(100000, 999999); Why not use auto increment?

Comment: You say you are getting a 'file not found' error for register-exec.php, however the code you posted doesn't have an `include` or `require` function in it. On what line are you receiving the error, and what code is on this line?

Comment: database has id auto cid is a form of login id that needs to be 6 digits long.

Comment: I use require_once on register-exec just under session start. But thats database. However, the reg_form uses the $_POST to submit info to register_exec

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your **reg_form.php**, **db_conn.php** and **register-exec.php** are in the same location or make sure to specify the path to them when calling/using them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to test, if you can call the files manually to see if it is a permission issue. Simply type into your browser the full path to the file.

Depending on how you copied it, you might not enjoy the same permissions on your production server and thus PHP can't access the file. Try setting it with

```
chmod 777 filename.php
```

and then if it works, make sure you revert back to the amount of privileges you need.

If the files are sitting in a different locations give the absolute path:

```
require_once("/var/config/my_config_files.php");
```

Comment: I've called them. db_conn.php is blank, reg_form.php displays the form, register-exec.php gives "Remote Server or File not found" error. All files reside in the same folder.

Comment: Does it work on your development server? Do you have any exclusion code that redirects direct calls to the PHP file when called in a browser? If so you would need to temporarily remove them when trying to access the file.

Comment: Production server had an old htaccess file that had url rewrite on. Development server is showing undefined function clean=() on 41

Comment: Where is this function located? In the register-exec.php?

Comment: I added this to correct the function error:   //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
 function clean($str) {
  $str = @trim($str);
  if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
   $str = stripslashes($str);
  }
  return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
 }

Comment: The function is before the clean = (). Or at least it should have been. Adding that, I found I had an error in my mysql query near the end, I forgot a couple of feilds.

Comment: I think PHP is smart enough to check if a function exists. If not, try to make sure the clean function sits before the actual position where you call it. Well in the end. If you cannot access the file directly on your server, it could mean that it's server related and has nothing to do with PHP especially if all the other files work fine together and you can also access them directly.

Comment: I've got it working on both, but once I click the link to activate, the page is blank, it should show success if its right.

Comment: Check your error files to see if something did not work. Try adding trace code (e.g. echo "Function 1 called."; etc.) to see how far you get in the files and why it does not call the function you want it to call. Maybe the SQL does not work, maybe its another problem. Very hard to diagnose from here as I cannot see it. If you are redirecting with header. Try if it works in a separate PHP file to exclude the possiblity of the web server being not able to understand the redirect command. Some require you to specifically mention the code.

Comment: header("HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location:index.php"); This is the order you want. Two headers and first the 301 moved header.

Comment: I'm going to move the activated portion from the register file, call it activated.php or something. I appreciate everyones help.

Comment: I would suggest to invest some time looking at the PDO class and "binding" variables to a prepared statement rather than making your own clean() function.